# Answered but unaccepted questions populating the main page

Tags: discussion

first post on meta!

I was wondering if there's anything that can be done with all the answered but unaccepted questions. This has been discussed on other metas and there are good reasons why questions like this are "allowed" to remain floating in the ether for eternity. I also believe, as GD is quite new, lots of users just pass by, learn how to solve something and never come back. Time will solve this, I'm sure. But looking at the main page now, do you think the accepted/unaccepted rate can affect in some way the active participation in the site? I know it's quite impossible to determine who could rate an answer as "accepted" if not the user, or if it's necessary at all. Do you think this can be a potential problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much. This problem has been brought up on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period), the answer is always that there isn't much that can be done. Basically, just try to encourage people to accept, but there's nothing else we can do really...

Comment: I guess you are right. I´ll start putting something like "don´t forget to accept this answer if this solved your problem" when the user is new. Thanks for answering!